# Need help querying unused id's in relational table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query my database for unused listId's but can't quite seem to get the query syntax correct. Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pkListId FROM tblList 
INNER JOIN InUseLists ON
tblList.pkListId NOT LIKE InUseLists.fkListId
```

Where tblList holds all List data, and InUseLists is a view holding all distinct listId's from my relational table.
Currently my tblList holds listId 1-9

my relational table has fkListId 1,8,9 (used more than once)

So my view gets distinct values from the relational table - 1,8,9.

What is wrong with my query syntax?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `left join` (which can succeed whether or not it finds a match in the "right" table), and then to select those rows where the join, in fact, failed to work.

Something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pkListId FROM tblList 
LEFT JOIN InUseLists ON
tblList.pkListId LIKE InUseLists.fkListId
WHERE InUseLists.fkListId is null
```

(If `LIKE` is the right operator here. Most joins use a simple equality check)

---

If this still isn't right, it might be better if you edited your question to include the sample data and expected results in a tabular form. At the moment, I'm still not sure what the contents of your tables are, and what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblList.pkListId, FROM tblList, InUseLists WHERE
tblList.pkListId NOT IN(InUseLists.fkListId)
```

Comment: similar effect to what I had - returns 1-9. but when I remove the NOT it only returns 1,8,9. I feel like I am missing something.